# App service alternative to Adobe Flash Media (Server & Live Encoder)

Tags: 11.10, server, streaming, adobe

I am looking for an alternative to Adobe Flash Media Server and Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder that can offer on the same hardware better performance, quality and overall performance/stability. I will be using a Pinnacle video capturing device to capture the video and transfer it to the server.

What alternative is available in Ubuntu so I can replace the whole Adobe system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Red5 is an open source Flash server that is written in Java and supports:

- streaming audio/video (FLV, MP3, F4V, MP4, AAC, M4A)
- recording client streams (FLV only)
- shared objects
- live stream publishing (Sorenson, VP6, h.264, MP3, AAC and more)

It has installers for OSX and Windows. Also, it can be downloaded as a zip file to be used in any OS.

OR

[image]

Mammoth is also an open source Flash streaming server that is built with C++ and can run on Windows and *nix OSs.

It can stream all Flash codecs like h263, h264, mp3, vp6, speex, nellymoser, etc.

By using FFmpeg it has has container support for most formats: mov, flv, mkv, mp3 and more.

The server is still in alpha phase but very promising.

ref http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-flash-media-server-alternatives/

Comment: Mammoth looks dead (Last update was on 2008) but Red5 is still active. Still, both have a very nice documentation (thank god). Thanks BlueXrider.

Answer (score 3):

You can also review Ant Media Server. Ant Media Server Low Latency solutions are awesome.

Ant Media Server is an open source media server that supports:

- Ultra Low Latency Adaptive One to Many WebRTC Live Streaming in Enterprise Edition
- Adaptive Bitrate for Live Streams (WebRTC, MP4, HLS) in Enterprise Edition
- SFU in One to Many WebRTC Streams in Enterprise Edition
- Live Stream Publishing with RTMP and WebRTC
- WebRTC to RTMP Adapter
- IP Camera Support
- Recording Live Streams (MP4 and HLS)
- Restream to Social Media Simultaneously(Facebook and Youtube in in Enterprise Edition)
- One-Time Token Control in Enterprise Edition
- Object Detection in Enterprise Edition

The Ant Media Server Github Page: https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server
The Ant Media Server Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ant-media-server
Also review website: https://antmedia.io

Answer (score 2):

RED5 with VLC does a lot of cool streaming. VLC as the encoder and RED5 as the media distribution server. VLC can act as a server as well, but I don't think is will scale as well as you wish.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the Red5 + VLC combination. Will test it out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about wowza media server, it's not free but it seems it's a little less then adobe. however keep in mind, if you don't own the server with a good backbone service you will likely be renting space on any of the servers, adobe, red5, wowza and what ever else is now available. the rent space plus bandwidth is usually pretty much the same cost no matter which platform you use, just a couple things to keep in mind before you try all the learning curves that each bring with them. If you go with red5 you will need to download and install the dev tools required for coding / programming in java and you will still need one of the newer flash IDE's as well.

red5 uses the eclipse IDE, For instructions on how to install the eclipse plugin, please see the following documentation on the red5.org site:
http://www.red5.org/red5-ide-plugin/

wowza also uses their own version of eclipse as well in their own IDE called wowza IDE2
http://www.wowza.com/

I have tried them all and I found that the support is excellent for wowza, you typically get straight forward answers in a timely manner, the other two mentioned not so much. aside from that it's all up to your skills and / or want to learn new ones. 
it's all java based in one form or another anyway.

I'm not going to post adobe site, everyone should know how to get there by now.

I hope this helps someone.